# How can I use .where() and .orderBy() together in react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

This is my code:
Please help me out
When I remove .where() condition or orderBy() (Anyone of them) code works fine but if I add both of them no error comes but reasult is empty

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: For the actual problem: This query requires that you add a composite index yourself. Check the log output of your app for error messages about a missing index, and click the link in there - which takes you to a page that creates the required index with a single click.